# Django - How to create a form to add a product and a variation to the cart?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I'm developing an e-commerce app to hone my django skills and I've reach the part where its time to add product with variations to the cart.

What would be the best approach for this?

My models structure is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.urls import reverse
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
# Create your models here.

class Brand(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    brand_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/PRODUCTS/BRANDS/LOGOS/')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('catalog:brand', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Category(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('catalog:category', args=[self.slug])

class Keywords(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product

class MetaKeywords(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keywords)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product

class ProductMetas(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    meta_description = RichTextField(max_length=300)
    meta_keywords = models.ForeignKey(MetaKeywords, related_name='meta_keywords', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product

class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/PRODUCTS/FEATURED_IMAGES/')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_image)

class ProductImageGallery(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImages)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product


class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.attribute
class ProductAttributesSet(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(ProductAttribute)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.product

class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.detail

class ProductDetailsList(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    details = models.ManyToManyField(ProductDetail, related_name='product_detail')

    def __str__(self):
            return self.product


class ProductSpecification(models.Model):
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.specification

class ProductSpecificationsSet(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    specifications = models.ManyToManyField(ProductSpecification, related_name='product_specification')

    def __str__(self):
                return self.product


class ProductVariableProductImages(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/PRODUCTS/VARIATIONS/')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_image)

class ProductVariableProductImageGallery(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImages)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product

class ProductVariable(models.Model):
    variation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/PRODUCTS/VARIATIONS/VARIABLE_IMAGES/', 
        blank=True, null=True)
    product_variable_image_gallery = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariableProductImageGallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price_regular = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    price_sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    product_UPC = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    product_SKU = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    product_MODEL_ID = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    stock_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    bestseller = models.BooleanField()
    featured = models.BooleanField()



class ProductVariations(models.Model):
    variations_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(ProductVariable)

class Product(models.Model):

    PRODUCT_TYPE = (

            ('single_product','Single product'),
            ('variable_product','Variable product'),
            ('groupped_product','Groupped product'),
        )

    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE)


    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)

    

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField()

    description_short = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description_long = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

    description_details_list = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetailsList, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='product_detail_list')

    specifications_set = models.ForeignKey(ProductSpecificationsSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_specifications_list')

    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/PRODUCTS/FEATURED_IMAGES/', 
        blank=True, null=True)
    image_gallery = models.ForeignKey(ProductImageGallery, 
        related_name='product_image_gallery', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        blank=True, 
        null=True)

    price_regular = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    price_sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    product_metas = models.ForeignKey(ProductMetas, 
        related_name='product_metas', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        blank=True, null=True)

    product_attributes_set = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttributesSet, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='product_attributes_set', 
        blank=True, 
        null=True)

    product_variations = models.ManyToManyField(ProductVariations,blank=True, null=True)

    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    product_UPC = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    product_SKU = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    product_MODEL_ID = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)


    STOCK_STATUS_OPTIONS = (
            ('in_stock','In stock'),
            ('out_of_stock','Out of stock'),
        
        )
    stock_status = models.CharField(max_length=300,choices=STOCK_STATUS_OPTIONS)

    stock_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)

    vendor = models.ForeignKey('vendors.Vendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_vendor')

    bestseller = models.BooleanField()
    featured = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('catalog:product', args=[self.slug])
```

my forms.py

```
from django  import  forms

from cart.models import CartItems
from cart.models import Cart
from orders.models import Order
from catalog.models import Product


class AddtoCartProductFormProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CartItems
        fields = '__all__'


class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product 
        fields = '__all__'
```

You can see how the models are related to each other. Based on this structure I would like create an add to cart form. What's the best way to this?

Thank you in advance.